# Cannot access instance variable/property of javascript object in clojurescipt

Tags: clojurescript

Chestnut project. Cider BREPL.

Using Three.js, I'm getting a simple color object:

```
(set! c  (js/THREE.Color. 0 0 255))
```

Examine the object:

```
clojoids-org.dev> (type c)
#<function ( color ) {

    if ( arguments.length === 3 ) {

        return this.setRGB( arguments[ 0 ], arguments[ 1 ], arguments[ 2 ] );

    }

    return this.set( color )

}>
```

I read this as it sets the color property.  However, when I try to get the color property, I get nil:

```
clojoids-org.dev> (.-color c)
-> nil
```

Tried aget as well:

```
clojoids-org.dev> (aget c "color")
->nil
```

As well as accessing RGB or setRGB (as suggested by the setRGB() call in the function):

```
clojoids-org.dev> (.-RGB c)
-> nil


clojoids-org.dev> (.-setRGB c)
#<function ( r, g, b ) {

        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;

        return this;

    }>
nil
clojoids-org.dev> (.-r  (.-setRGB c))
nil
clojoids-org.dev> (.-b  (.-setRGB c))
nil
clojoids-org.dev> (.-g  (.-setRGB c))
nil
```

Either it's genuinely nil because I'm not setting color properly, or I am not accessing it properly.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, shortly after posting this question, I discovered this worked:

```
clojoids-org.dev> (.-r c)
0
clojoids-org.dev> (.-g c)
0
clojoids-org.dev> (.-b c)
255
```

Thus the problem was I was not accessing it properly.